# Shopping cart: How to store product amount in database

Tags: mysql, shopping-cart

I am building a very small shopping cart system with php/mysql. Currently the actual shopping cart (less tables for products, categories and such) consists of two tables.

One table named shoppingCarts which includes the following columns:

- id (PK)
- userId(FK)
- dateCreated

The other table, named shoppingCartItems, consists of:

- productId (FK)
- shoppingCartId (FK)
- dateCreated

To add the amount of one product I can think of two possible scenarios:

1. Add a new row for each item added to the shopping cart.
2. Add a column 'amount' and store the amount in there.

I am wondering which option would be best, what are the ups and downs?
Maybe there is an even better solution I didn't think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the right solution is to have an extra column for the amount, because there is no advantage having one row per item but more redundant data. Imagine if the customer wants 50 items, you would end up with 50 identical rows of data. And you have to count the rows, either with a GROUP BY select or programatically. With the extra amount column you save data and your queries are less complex.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is that there is no use of using only an amount column.
As I believe you have an item table where you have the item id, details and its price.
So the flow goes like::
If a customer logs in create a row in shopping cart with his userId, and whenever he adds an item to his cart a new row is created to shopping cart items. Now the cumulative price of all the items can be found and displayed(using the aggregate function sum), which will solve the purpose of creating a new column "amount".
Moving forward, say in your application if you integrate the concept of discount coupons or any discounts to any loyal customer, our design will be tough to integrate. So what I suggest is adding two columns 
1) Total Price
2) Discounted Price/ Amount Paid
Please revert in any case of any doubts.